# Avoiding template verbosity and dynamic polymorphism with types known at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, polymorphism

In my [collision/game physics engine](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVSCollision), I allow the user to create/specify a preferred spatial parititioning method and a preferred resolution method.

Here's an example with spatial partitioning.

```
struct SpatialBase
{
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual void b() = 0;
    ...
};

struct Grid2D : public SpatialBase { ... override a() and b() ... };
struct QuadTree : public SpatialBase { ... override a() and b() ... };

struct World
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Body>> bodies;
    std::unique_ptr<SpatialBase> spatial;
    ...
    World(SpatialBase* mSpatial, ...) : spatial(mSpatial), ... { }
};

auto world1{new World{new Grid2D{...}, ...}};
auto world2{new World{new QuadTree{...}, ...}};
```

This works fine, but the dynamic polymorphism is completely unnecessary. Fact is, a templatized version of `World` would be too verbose, as a resolution method also needs to be specified, and the `Body` class must be aware of it.

Example:

```
auto world1{new World<Grid2D, ImpulseRes>(...)}; // fine
auto& body1{world1.createBody()}; // still fine

void useBody(auto& mBody) { ... }
// illegal! Wish I could use auto& here.

void useBody(Body<Grid2D, ImpulseRes>& mBody) { ... } 
// legal - but verbose, and what if the user decides to change 
// spatial partitioning or resolution? All code would break.
```

Is there a way to *hide* the `Grid2D` and `ImpulseRes` types? They only need to be known when the `World` is created. But `Body` must also be aware of those types, as it needs a reference to the spatial partitioning method instance and the resolution method instance.

Desired code example:

```
World world1{new World<Grid2D, ImpulseRes>(...)};
Body& body1{world1.createBody()}; 

void useBody(Body& mBody) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a good old-fashioned `typedef`.

```
typedef basic_world<grid2d, impulse_res> world;
typedef basic_body<world> body;

world world1(...);
void useBody(body& bdy) { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
template <class TGrid, class TImpulse>
void useBody(Body<TGrid, TImpulse>& mBody) { ... }
```

or

```
template <class TBody>
void useBody(TBody& mBody) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code is partitioned, but if you declare your function after instantiating `body1`, maybe you could use `decltype`:

```
auto& body1 = world1.createBody();

using body_type = decltype(body1);

void useBody(body_type& b) { ... }
```